# Best Practice for Loading Multiple Datasets on Same Webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm trying to develop a web page that queries a MySQL database depending on the user action, but I'm struggling to figure out what the best practice method would be.

*As an example, if the user hovers over option A, show the data relating to A from the database. If the user hovers over option B, show the data relating to B from the database. This means I only ever have to display 1 set of data at any point in time.*

The way I see it I have the following options, but I'd love to hear if there are better ways.

**OPTION 1**

Query the entire database initially, load into however many elements are required, hide them all and only show the relevant element on hover. From a quick search of others sites this doesn't appear to be a common approach, so I'm guessing this isn't best practice.

**OPTION 2**

EDIT: This option might be a bad idea, I don't want new data to come through. Data should be based on the time of page load.

Query the database on hover with AJAX, and populate a specific element with the result. To be honest this seems impractical, and adds some risk of database connection failures. BUT, it does mean that I won't have to load all the data at once and populate a heap of hidden elements.

**OPTION 3**

Query the entire database, but only load the elements when required - is this even possible?

*(Note: I'm using a combination of PHP and Javascript)*

Comment: Did your Option 2 involve using AJAX?

Comment: Yep that would involve AJAX

Answer (score 1):

The first option really depends on the amount of data to query. If you know that you only have a very small amount of elements, then it is viable, but otherwise it's really inefficient and impractical.

The second option takes care of the problem that I just discussed regarding the first option but will involve the use of ajax.

The third still queries the whole database even though loads the elements when required.

So, I guess, it's better to go with the second option. To have a little risk of database connection failures in lieu of querying the whole database and loading all the elements is fair.

Comment: Just having another think about it, option 2 with AJAX might be problematic. I don't necessarily want newer data to come through on hover, it should be data at the time of page load. Do you know a good way to implement option 3? (There would be around 50 records loaded by the way.)

Comment: Yes I think that is possible though you'd still have to request data via ajax. You can just pass the identifier that you want record of and then filter it on your php end through the collection of records queried from database, return the requested data and then inserting it into the DOM. If you have any doubts please feel free to ask.

Comment: If I return all the data on load via php and store it into an array would I be able to then reference the same array on hover (still AJAX as you mentioned)?

Comment: Yes of course, as the same php script will exist (containing the results queried from the database) unless the page refreshes or you move to some other page which would not happen in this case, thanks to AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 supports what you want natively with the `title` attribute.

```
<div title="17 left in stock! Order now!">7-port USB-C hub</div>
```

This will show the "title" text when your user hovers over the item. So, include `title` attribute data in your HTML and you're done.

AJAX operations ([or the easier-to-use fetch() in modern HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)) is good for dynamically loading new information into your page. But your requirement doesn't seem to call for that. You want the information to be loaded with the page.

If you don't like the default styling of `title` popups you can change it. Look up "styling HTML tooltips" and you'll see lots of tutorials.

(Keep in mind that touchscreen mobile devices can't do hover operations).

Answer (score 0):

Why not go with Option 2 and on the initial page load, save a timestamp in some html tag like
`<div data-page-loaded-at="{{ timestamp/formatted date }}" style="display: none;" />`?
You can then add the timestamp to your AJAX requests and fetch data depending on the provided time. This is of course not a good practice, if you don't want users on the frontend to be able to manipulate the data fetched by changing that timestamp.

Comment: With jQuery you could access that data like $('[data-page-loaded-at]').attr('data-page-loaded-at')